# Left Join in a many to many relation in Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I shouldn't use raw query and it lead to this mess! Can you please help me to improve it.

```
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        {{ Form::bsText($attribute->name, $attribute->title, $customer->attributes()->find($attribute->id)->pivot->value ?? '') }}
@endforeach
```

Attribute Model:

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
}
```

Customer Model:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)->withPivot('value');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
{
    $attributes = Attribute::all();
    return view('admin.customers.show', compact('customer', 'attributes'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Frist option:**

You can rearrenge indexes of customer attributes collection to attribute id, and access models in customer attributes collection via id.

Controller:

```
$attributes = Attribute::all();
$customer = Customer::with('attribues')...
$customer->attributes = $customer->attributes->keyBy('id');
```

View:

```
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        {{ Form::bsText($attribute->name, $attribute->title, $customer->attributes[$attribute->id]->pivot->value ?? '') }}
@endforeach
```

**Second option:**

This option based on work with collection `->attributes` instead of relation `->attributes()` to reduce count of db queries.

Controller:

```
$attributes = Attribute::all();
$customer = Customer::with('attribues')...
```

View:

```
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        {{ Form::bsText($attribute->name, $attribute->title, $customer->attributes->where('id', $attribute->id)->first()->pivot->value ?? '') }}
@endforeach
```

First option should be faster than second.

Comment: Such a great idea `->keyBy('id')`, Thanks!